# has_many through associations merge causes N+1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following rails app which pulls in websites information.

```
class Website < ApplicationRecord
 has_many :details
 has_many :urls, through: :details
end

class Detail < ApplicationRecord
 belongs_to :website
 belongs_to :url
end

class Url < ApplicationRecord
 has_many :details
 has_many :websites, through: :details
end

websites = Websites.joins(:urls, :details).includes(:urls, :details).paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 10)
```

This is a typical has_many through associations. However, when I try to merge JSON output in the active model serialization, I get N+1 issue.

```
class WebsiteSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
 attributes :results

def results
  {websiteinfo: website_info_with_details}
end
def website_info_with_details
  object.detail.map do |k|
    k.attributes.merge(k.url.attributes)
  end
end
```

why is it causing N+1 although as you can see above I'm including both tables above? when I remove the line `k.attributes.merge(k.url.attributes)` the N+1 issue disappears but I lose url information showing in my feed. any suggestions why this is happening?

Comment: What is `v`? What is `v.url?` I don't think it is the same as the `urls` you're preloading

Comment: Sorry was a typo should be k. Updated that.

Comment: Max, do you know why N+1 is happening ?

Comment: @maxpleaner I added more details to the question as well.

Comment: i am not sure...

Comment: First, I think you can remove `joins`, just keep `includes`. Second, `object.details` instead of `object.detail`. 

What happen when you remove the `includes` ? Can u tell differences if you have `includes` and you dont' have `includes`. If `include` does nothing this case, when you remove `k.attributes.merge(k.url.attributes)` it should still have N+1 queries. In my opinion, just remove `joins` because of unnecessary. This serializer performs eager loading already

Comment: @quyetdc thanks, let me try that and get back to you!